# Property "value" does not exist on type Readonly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning how to develop applications using React as front-end and spring as back-end. While developing a sample application, I encountered an error as follows:

```
       `(26,28): Property "value" does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>`
```

This error is generated from my App.tsx file which contains the React Components definition in JSX.
The class component with the state "value" is defined as follows.

```
class App extends React.component{
        constructor(props:any) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
             value:[],
             isLoading:false
          };
       }
        ...
25      render(){
26        const value = this.state.value;
27        const isLoading = this.state.isLoading;
          ... 
    }
   }//End of Class*
```

I am not understanding what's wrong. Can someone please help me look at it in a different perspective so that this problem can be approached in a different manner?

Comment: Please change your title to describe the problem or question, not your project.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Did you declare an interface for your `state`?

Take a look at [Hello React and TypeScript](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/TypeScriptAndReact.html) which shows an example of using interfaces with React Components.

I suspect you're missing something like this:

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
    someDefaultValue: string
}

interface IMyComponentState {
    someValue: string
}

class App extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, IMyComponentState> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, All I had to do was React.Component<{},any> instead of React.Component. But got the idea from this post... Thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167263/why-my-object-from-import-let-is-readonly-react-js?noredirect=1#comment91288499_52167263 Any suggestion for this

Answer (score 6):

could you please try this as follow.

```
class App extends React.component<{},any>{ //your code}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    export default class ReactTodoWebpart extends React.Component<IReactTodoWebpartProps,any> {
  /**
   *
   */
  constructor(props:IReactTodoWebpartProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      todoItems:[]
    };
    this.props.todoClient.getItems().then(resolvedItems=>{
      this.setState({
        todoItems: resolvedItems,

      })
    });

  }
// I also face this issue and fixed it by using any in the second argument
```